# Delay Payments on Paypal

Tags: codeigniter, paypal, e-commerce, payment-gateway, payment-processing

Is there anyway that system can process a payment later on. when ever a customer do a payment using paypal on our website but transaction not processing immediately. we giving the customer a period of time, and when it past some number of days system automatically process the transaction. then only money reducing from customer's account. is this possible to do ?
i'm using paypal API with codeignitor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, it is called "Payment Preapproval" which is part of PayPal Adaptive Payments. You can find more information here:

[documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-basicPreapproval-curl-etc/)

Basically you will need to redirect the user to PayPal in order to approve a payment which you can later process by yourself or automatically by PayPal.

If you know how to make a express checkout payment this topic will be very familiar.

Answer (score 2):

Preapproval is one method, but I would recommend using Reference Transactions instead.  These can be done with both PayPal Express Checkout checkouts as well as Payments Pro (direct credit card).  It will offer a much better experience for your users.

This [PayPal CodeIgniter library](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-codeigniter) will make all the API calls very quick and easy for you regardless of which method you choose to use.

Comment: Thank You for your help. i'm already using a PayPal CodeIgniter library for normal payments. issue came up with Adaptive Payments. now its been solved. thanks again.